# html file upload using multipart retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I want to upload html file using retrofit multipart. But it throws error code 422. I am creating multipart below.

```
@NonNull
    private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(File file, Context context) {

        // create RequestBody instance from file
        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse("text/*"), file);


        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);
    }
```

I have tried media type ="text/*" , "text/plain", "text/html", "multipart/form-data" & context.getContentResolver().getType(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath())).
What is am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Get mime type using **MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(String url)**. this returns the file extension of given url or return an empty string if there is no extension.
Find complete code below.

```
 @NonNull
    public MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(Context context, String partName, Uri fileUri) {
        // create RequestBody instance from file

        File file = FileUtils.getFile(context, fileUri);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
            imageBytes = FileUtils.getBytes(inputStream, inputStream.available());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getMimeType(file)), imageBytes);
        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
    }

        public static String getMimeType(File file) {
            String extension = null;
            //Check uri format to avoid null
            if (file != null)
                extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getPath());

            return extension;
        }

public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                    "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                            ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                            ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                            ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                            ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                            ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                            ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
            );

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider
            if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                // The path is the id
                return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            }
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            else if (isFieProviderUri(uri))
                return uri.getPath();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

/**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     */
    public static boolean isLocalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isFieProviderUri(Uri uri) {
        return Constants.FILE_AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {
        Log.w(TAG, uri.toString());

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA;
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what is FileUtils? can u share please ?

Comment: i still can not resolve getBytes() , isLocal() method. and what is import for "AUTHORITY".equals(uri.getAuthority()) , and "Constants".FILE_AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority()). can you share it?

Comment: replace FILE_AUTHORITY with your file provider authorities that you added in Manifest file with "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" provider and AUTHORITY is "android.provider.ContactsContract.AUTHORITY"